# Mono 3.x support for OS X 10.6

Tags: c#, macos, mono, osx-snow-leopard

I am working on a cross platform application using Mono. In the past we have had no issues with our application running on 10.6.8 (which constitutes our minimum supported OS X version). Recently however, after changing our app's required version of Mono to 3.x (required for OS X 10.9+ support) we found that our application crashes at startup for OS X 10.6.8 and older.

I have been trying to figure out what is causing the crash but have been overall unsuccessful. While attempting to find a solution I have come across comments in various places which hint to the fact the Mono 3.x no longer supports OS X 10.6 anymore, however I can't find any official documentation supporting these claims:

===============================================================================

https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=14137#c4
http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/mac/getting_started/installation/ (Xamarin hints to this effect in their **"Requirements"** section).

===============================================================================

I was hoping someone might be able to point me to some official documentation or perhaps could confirm that Mono 3.x does not support 10.6 anymore (it'd be better to let users know 10.6 is no longer supported because Mono no longer supports it not because we mistakenly thought Mono dropped supported for 10.6).

I am not trying to ask for help with our crash, I am just trying to get confirmation regarding Mono 3.x and it's support for older versions of OS X (if it turns out that Mono 3.x does support OS X 10.6 then I will post a separate question regarding the bug we are experiencing )

Comment: please be specific about the **exact** version of mono 3.x you are using

Comment: I am using Mono 3.2.4.

Comment: This question seems legit to me. It either is or isn't supported, OP is just looking for a source to confirm.